# Create dropping ball

Tags: android

When the play button is pressed to start the game(activity), I'd like to create the instance of a ball falling from the top of the screen (the ball will hit something later). I'm not sure how to go about it. Can anyone assist?

What I'm working with so far:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Turn title off
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // set Game to fullscreen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        View ballView = new BallView(this);
        setContentView(ballView);
        // ballView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class BallView extends View {

    // Ball attributes
    private float ballRadius = 30;
    private float ballX = 50;
    private float ballY = 50;
    private RectF ballBounds;
    private Paint ballColor;
    // For game elements
    private int score = 0;

    public BallView(Context context){
        super(context);
        // Initialize game elements
        ballBounds = new RectF();
        ballColor = new Paint();
        this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        // Draw ball
        ballBounds.set(ballX - ballRadius, ballY - ballRadius, ballX + ballRadius, ballY + ballRadius);
        ballColor.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawOval(ballBounds, ballColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: To add, I'd like the ball to come down directly at the center from the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description of your intent, you should probably use OpenGL or a framework like [libgdx](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) which has physics and collision detection built in.

But to answer you question, you try this quick example:

```
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;

public class BallView extends View{

    // Ball attributes
    private float ballRadius = 30;
    private float ballX = 50;
    private float ballY = 50;
    private float ballSpeed = 10.0f;
    private RectF ballBounds;
    private Paint ballColor;
    boolean doBallAnimation = false;
    // For game elements
    private int score = 0;
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
    long startTime, prevTime; // Used to track elapsed time for animations and fps

    public BallView(Context context){
        super(context);
        // Initialize game elements
        ballBounds = new RectF();
        ballColor = new Paint();
        this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout(){
                        getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                        ballY = 0;
                        ballX = (getWidth()- ballRadius) / 2.0f;

                        doBallAnimation = true;
                        animator.start();
                    }
                }
        );

        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator arg0){
                long nowTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                float secs = (float)(nowTime - prevTime) / 1000f;
                prevTime = nowTime;

                if((ballY + ballSpeed) > (getHeight() - (ballRadius)))
                {
                    animator.cancel();
                    return;
                }

                ballY += ballSpeed;

                // Force a redraw to see the ball in its new position
                invalidate();
            }
        });
        animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        animator.setDuration(3000);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        // Draw ball
        if(doBallAnimation)
        {
            ballBounds.set(ballX - ballRadius, ballY - ballRadius, ballX + ballRadius, ballY + ballRadius);
            ballColor.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawOval(ballBounds, ballColor);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. Much appreciated. Worked exactly as I'd like.

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)